# The use of refer to: Active or Passive?

Tags: active-voice, passive-voice

Are the uses of the phrase 'refer to' as follows correct?

- The methodology in this research referred to UNESCO.
- The methodology in this research was referred to UNESCO.

I believe what the writer wants to say is 'the methodology used in this research is the same methodology that UNESCO uses.' Thanks so much.

Comment: Please explain what the sentences are supposed to mean.  How can methodology make reference to something?  A description of methodology might do so, but not the methodology itself.

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things. The first means that the methodology mentioned UNESCO. The second means that the methodology was passed to UNESCO. At least, it would if the verb showed agreement with the subject, as it does when rewritten as ‘The methodology in this research **was** referred to UNESCO.

It isn't clear from your examples in isolation exactly what the writer is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that what the writer wants to say is "For the methodology in this research, we refer the reader to UNESCO." If this is the case, then ***both*** are wrong.

The writer may be trying to avoid using terms like "the reader", "we", "you", and so forth. I don't believe it is possible to write this using the word "refer", but without using any of these terms. To use the verb "refer", one has to specify either a subject or an object.